# Get WooCommerce mixed 10 products from multiple product categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to get 10 products from multiple categories and this is my code:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'product_cat'    => 'ring,watch,earring'
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I'm getting 10 products from the first category only.

Is there any way to get 10 mixed products from multiple categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Your code is a bit outdated, instead try the following to query products from specific product category terms **using the argument "orderby" set to "rand"** *(random order by)* to make them mixed up:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'       => 'rand',
    'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array('ring', 'watch', 'earring'),
     ) ),
) );
```

Tested and work.

Comment: It is the same actually, it brings all products from the fist category which is "ring" and after that the second then the third

Comment: @MahmoudOfeisa Updated:  I had a typo on `order_by` argument that need to be instead `orderby` without an underscore. I tested that and it works now.